# Share same access of controller for different html in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using ionic 4, 
is there any way to share the access of component controller for different HTML ?

[image]

I mean, I need "`network-cell-content.html`" access to the same variable in "`rw-network-cell.component.ts`"

Comment: look for ngTemplateOutlet

Comment: @mr.void thanks, but that will work when both of templates in the same file, not as my case in separated files.

Comment: You create a service that hosts the variable you want to use and inject that service in both components

Comment: @Mehdi No, I need my custom HTML "network-cell" access the same variable that declares in component.ts

Comment: Yes, you need to inject the same service in both component, that service has a variable used/updated by both components